# R - alternative to for loop for selective "dragging down"

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset in which there are multiple columns, most of which contain a value in each cell.

However, one of the columns has a "title" which appears in an empty line at the top of each "block" of data. (Thanks, Sage!)

I want to "copy down" the "title" column values selectively.  I've written a for loop to do this, but it was quite slow as I have 200,000 rows (and despite being a new R user, I know for loops are bad news in R generally).  Is there an alternative solution?

```
 Current:
          Title1    
Col1 Col2       Col3
Col1 Col2       Col3
Col1 Col2       Col3
Col1 Col2       Col3
         Title2
Col1 Col2       Col3
Col1 Col2       Col3
Col1 Col2       Col3
Col1 Col2       Col3



      Desired:
          Title1    
Col1 Col2 Title1 Col3
Col1 Col2 Title1 Col3
Col1 Col2 Title1 Col3
Col1 Col2 Title1 Col3
         Title2
Col1 Col2 Title2 Col3
Col1 Col2 Title2 Col3
Col1 Col2 Title2 Col3
Col1 Col2 Title2 Col3
```

Comment: Are you aware of `na.locf()` from the `zoo` package. It might work here. You can also define an entire column like this `df1<-data.frame(matrix(NA,5,1))`. `df1[,1]<-"NotNA"`.Just so you know.

Comment: What is the format of your data? Can you `dput` the first bit of it?